# align-items working different for different gird items. small problem

Tags: html, css, css-grid

one of my grid items has an image and a text, while others have only a text. this makes them work differently when I use align. How do I fix this.

HTML code. Ignore the nav bar.

CSS file. Again ignore the nav bar. Nav bar is the one with the classes. My issue is the one where I use ids.

here is the codepen link
https://codepen.io/aronnora/pen/qBdMReM

HTML

```
    <div id="container">
      <div id="grid">
        <div id="firbo">
          <div id="image1"></div>
          <div id="text1">
          <h1>のイプサム</h1>
          <p>情試をー今17須ナヱホ引数73挑だこ待視んばろ愛告げ掲謝クエ群読建ヱ弥設もゃ真安仮稼こゃむぎ。復ものま堀福ユメ職質キ除負すかへ者屋神ユヤネ際舵雇ぽ局面スヲサ緑評だでひ巨1名し帯始レ引会ずゅリ図伝いけょ。事タ職動チヌルミ活75道ドむ発一意コヒヨ系経れわずル様上ケヲ是誠ぴ株95複ミサカ掲数図軽ル方近ゅ必来げ前更ろドっだ質写スもレみ席記ハモヨネ戦径リぼ</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="secbo">
          <h1>のイプサム</h1>
          <p>情試をー今17須ナヱホ引数73挑だこ待視んばろ愛告げ掲謝クエ群読建ヱ弥設もゃ真安仮稼こゃむぎ。復ものま堀福ユメ職質キ除負すかへ者屋神ユヤネ際舵雇ぽ局面スヲサ緑評だでひ巨1名し帯始レ引会ずゅリ図伝いけょ。事タ職動チヌルミ活75道ドむ発一意コヒヨ系経れわずル様上ケヲ是誠ぴ株95複ミサカ掲数図軽ル方近ゅ必来げ前更ろドっだ質写スもレみ席記ハモヨネ戦径リぼ。</p>
        </div>
        <div id="thirbo">
          <h1>のイプサム</h1>
          <p>情試をー今17須ナヱホ引数73挑だこ待視んばろ愛告げ掲謝クエ群読建ヱ弥設もゃ真安仮稼こゃむぎ。復ものま堀福ユメ職質キ除負すかへ者屋神ユヤネ際舵雇ぽ局面スヲサ緑評だでひ巨1名し帯始レ引会ずゅリ図伝いけょ。事タ職動チヌルミ活75道ドむ発一意コヒヨ系経れわずル様上ケヲ是誠ぴ株95複ミサカ掲数図軽ル方近ゅ必来げ前更ろドっだ質写スもレみ席記ハモヨネ戦径リぼ。</p>
        </div>
        <div id="forbo">
          <h1>のイプサム</h1>
          <p>情試をー今17須ナヱホ引数73挑だこ待視んばろ愛告げ掲謝クエ群読建ヱ弥設もゃ真安仮稼こゃむぎ。復ものま堀福ユメ職質キ除負すかへ者屋神ユヤネ際舵雇ぽ局面スヲサ緑評だでひ巨1名し帯始レ引会ずゅリ図伝いけょ。事タ職動チヌルミ活75道ドむ発一意コヒヨ系経れわずル様上ケヲ是誠ぴ株95複ミサカ掲数図軽ル方近ゅ必来げ前更ろドっだ質写スもレみ席記ハモヨネ戦径リぼ。</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows:46.29rem;
  grid-template-areas: "firbo secbo thirbo forbo";
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  justify-items: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#firbo{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  grid-area: firbo;
}
#text1{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

#image1{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width:10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-image: url(tesla_logo_PNG16.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}
#secbo{
  grid-area: secbo;
}
#thirbo{
  grid-area: thirbo;
}
#forbo{
  padding-right: 1rem;
  grid-area: forbo;
}
```

Comment: Can u share a link to codepen or something?

Comment: here: https://codepen.io/aronnora/pen/qBdMReM

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to do with which elements? Please remove code that we have to ignore from your question.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Done. Also I got the answer by another user. I just wanted the four grid-items to be aligned when I used "align-items: center". But the first grid element was vertically lower than the others. That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `position: absolute;` for `#text1`

```
#text1 {
    /* position: absolute; */
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixes it. But I don't understand why? and why remove position only from text and not from image?

Comment: @AniketVishwakarma For your case, alignment is only for non-absolute of position part, so you need to put text for alignment. On the other hand, you can try to remove image1 (absolute) div, and It does not affect alignment.